# Classes, objects and lists in python

Tags: python, class

so I'm trying to create a program but I still have difficulties with classes. The program (which isn't finished of course) will print a random number of Villages. Each village(second Class) will have a random number of Clans(the first Class). Anyway my problem is the Village class. How do I make sure to add the areas and family size into the Village class? How do I insert the counter from the Clan class to the Village class? As you can see when I've randomized a number of Clans the areas and family sizes should add up into the Village class. What should I do? What is wrong with my Village class?

```
class Clan:
 counter = 0

 def __init__(self):
    r = random.randrange(20, 101)
    self.area = r
    s = random.randrange(1, 6)
    self.familySize = s
    Clan.counter += 1
    self.counter = Clan.counter

 def getArea(self):
    return self.area

 def getFamilySize(self):
    return self.familySize


class Village:
 counter = 0

 def __init__(self):
    self.clan_list = []
    for i in range(random.randrange(3, 7)): 
        self.clan_list += [Clan()]
 def getclan_list(self):
    return self.clan_list
 def getArea(self):
    return self.area
 def getPopulation(self):
    pass
```

Comment: Hello I dont know what you are trying to do here    
Clan.counter += 1
self.counter = Clan.counter

Clan.counter always will be 0, if you want to modify the instance you have to use self.

Comment: What does it mean to insert the clan counter into the village? I don't follow your line of thought. The rest I get, just not the clan counter being inserted into a village.

Comment: @lapinkoira: `Clan.counter` is a class attribute; it won't always be 0. Test the `Clan` class for yourself & see what happens.

Comment: Maybe provide an example input and output? That might help.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the village class to calculate how many families are in the village?

```
families = 0
for clan in self.clan_list
    families += clan.getFamilySize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the values of area and population are dependent on the clans in `clan_list` you should compute these values each time they are needed. The alternative is much more complicated -- having to control how clans are added and removed from the village *and* how the area and family size of a clan can be changed and having those changes reflected in the village.

Below is an example of how you might compute both village area and population. The first using a getter method, and the second using a more python-esque property.

```
import random

class Clan:
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        r = random.randrange(20, 101)
        self.area = r
        s = random.randrange(1, 6)
        self.familySize = s
        Clan.counter += 1
        self.counter = Clan.counter

    # removed getters
    # Unless your getter or setter is doing something special,
    # just access the attribute directly.



class Village:

    def __init__(self):
        self.clan_list = []
        for i in range(random.randrange(3, 7)): 
            self.clan_list.append(Clan())

    # for a village, area is a computed value, so use a getter
    def getArea(self):
        total_area = 0
        for clan in self.clan_list:
            total_area += clan.area
        return total_area

    # the prefered alternative to getters (and setters) are properties
    # note that the function is named as if it was an attribute rather than function
    @property
    def population(self):
        # use sum and generator rather than a for loop
        return sum(clan.familySize for clan in self.clan_list)


# How to use a village instance
v = Village()
# get area
print("area:", v.getArea())
# get population
print("population:", v.population)
# note how population is accessed as if it was an attribute rather than called 
# like a function
```